# What is the correct way to return booleans from something like an insert function?

Tags: java, insert, linked-list, boolean

I'm playing around with implementing a linked list that has an insert function that returns true once the node has been inserted. What is the correct way to conceptually return false in this type of scenario?

```
public boolean insert(int d) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new Node(d);
            return true;
        }

        if (head.data > d) {
            Node holder = head;
            Node newNode = new Node(d);
            head = newNode;
            head.next = holder;
            holder.prev = newNode;
            return true;
        }

        Node tmpNode = head;

        while (tmpNode.next != null && tmpNode.next.data < d) {
            tmpNode = tmpNode.next;
        }

        Node prevTmp = tmpNode;         
        Node insertedNode = new Node(d);

        if (tmpNode.next != null) {
            Node nextTmp = tmpNode.next;
            insertedNode.next = nextTmp;
            nextTmp.prev = insertedNode;
        } 
        prevTmp.next = insertedNode;
        insertedNode.prev = prevTmp;    
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you're asking when you'd want to return `false`, the typical answer is "when the function fails." If the function cannot fail, there's no reason to return a status. You could return, say, the head of the list, or the item that was just inserted, if either of those would be helpful. Otherwise, it's fine to make the function type `void`.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  There's nowhere where the function fails.  Are we talking a maximum capacity or a uniqueness constraint?

Comment: `new` can fail, but it should throw an exception. It's up to the author to decide what the constraints should be, if there are any.

Comment: Ok actually that makes sense. For some reason, when I was checking Java's linkedlist documentation earlier, I thought add() returned a boolean. So I was wondering what type of scenario they were handling with returning false. But it actually returns void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case insert() method should be void since you are returnung true in all situtations. Returning boolean means that there are situations when you cannot insert an element into the collection, eg duplicates are not allowed